# Selenium Wait Synchronize with IE and Firefox Timeout

Tags: python, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium

I have a simple need. Using the latest Selenium-RC Server and Selenium Client on Python 2.7, I just want to find a COMMON way to know when a browser cannot access a page (for example when IE8 throws error 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'). Effectively,

I want Selenium exceptions/timeouts to Synchronize with browser Timeouts!!

Here is an example of problem I am facing.

When I run these simple Python Code, the results vary with browsers...
Code-

```
>>> from selenium import selenium
>>> s1 = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*iexplore', 'http:///')
>>> s1.start()
>>> s1.open('http://xxxxxxxx')
>>> s1.open('http://1.1.1.1')
```

For IE8, the page display "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", but Selenium throws no exception!! Meaning, Selenium's default timeout is not reached.

For Firefox, the page displays 'Server not found' and Selenium waits for the timeout and finally times out giving this error-

```
>>> s1.open('http://xxxxxxxx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.11.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\selenium.py", line 774, in open
    self.do_command("open", [url,ignoreResponseCode])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.11.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\selenium.py", line 214, in do_command
    raise Exception, data
Exception: Timed out after 30000ms
>>>
```

Same applies when I do s1.open('http://1.1.1.1') with Firefox.

Why is there a difference?